# Why do I get Imaginary unit after Abs and Complex expand?

Tags: functions, complex, variable-definitions

I am getting an imaginary unit in the output after Abs and saying Complex Expand, why? Then, when I integrate in x and z, I miss beta. I don't get why beta vanishes in the definite integral.

```
IntegrandSerie[beta_, x_, z_] = 
ComplexExpand@
Abs[Series[(1 - (1 - I)/2*Sqrt[beta/2]*
      Cosh[(1 - I)*z*
         Sqrt[beta/2]]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*Sqrt[ beta/2]]))*(dWNorm[
     x]) + (Z0 I beta dWNorm1/
      2)*(Sinh[(1 - I) Sqrt[
        beta/2] z]/((1 - I) Sqrt[
         beta/2] Cosh[(Sqrt[beta/2] (1 - I)/2)] - 
       2 Sinh[Sqrt[beta/2] (1 - I)/2]))*(S[x]), {beta, 0, 1}]]^2
IntegralSerie = 
Integrate[IntegrandSerie[beta, x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

Comment: Look up the `TargetFunctions` option of `ComplexExpand[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I have checked and inserted TargetFunctions->{Abs, Arg} but still I get that imaginary unit.

Comment: I suppose it may be because it's a series.  Try `ComplexExpand[Abs[s], {_SeriesData}]` for your series `s`.  I think without the extra argument, it converts `Abs[s]` to  `Sqrt[s^2]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 what is the part {_SeriesData}? And what do you mean by extra argument? Shall I substitute something in SeriesData or just copy?

Comment: It's a pattern that matches `SeriesData`, which is the output of `Series`. (Try `InputForm@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 5}]`, for instance.)  Use it just as I typed, but substitute your series for `s`. In `ComplexExpand`, expressions that match the patterns in the second argument are assumed to be complex-valued.  Without the "extra" `{_SeriesData}` argument, `ComplexExpand` does the `Sqrt` of `s^2`.  See `Blank[]` for more on the pattern.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Mmmm, I am a bit new to Mathematica.Regarding my case, without entering to deep in the documentation, shall I substitute for s my expression and for SeriesData the {beta,0,1}?

Comment: Replace `s` by the whole series, `Series[...{beta, 0, 1}]`, and leave everything else the same in `ComplexExpand[Abs[s]^2, {_SeriesData}]` -- I forgot the `^2` earlier.

Comment: Ar some point, though, you're going to have to wade into the documentation or you won't understand what your code is doing....

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see. Of course, I'll look in the documentation step by step, but sometimes I  can't get the solution from there. For example, I have to inform you that in the end when computing the final integral, I dont get anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56945/discussion-between-andrea-g-and-michael-e2).